# Better writing of a static Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, enumeration

I am keeping a static dictionary to map a simple integer stored in a database to an enum value.

```
static Dictionary<long, EModelType> AttributeIdTypeToEModelType = 
   new Dictionary<long, EModelType>()
   {
      {1, EModelType.StatStr},
      {6, EModelType.HistStr},
      {7, EModelType.HistVal}
   };
```

The great advantage is that I use it to directly get my enum value as the data arrive from the database.

```
typ = AttributeIdTypeToEModelType[i];
```

The usage of this system is neat, but it doesn't look clean to me to have a static dictionary just for this.

I had no chance trying to find a cleaner way to use enumerators and overriding their values.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a `Dictionary` to cast an `int` to the appropriate `Enum` type:

```
var type = (EModelType)yourInt;
```

or using [`Enum.ToObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.toobject.aspx):

```
var type = Enum.ToObject(typeof(EModelType) , yourInt);
```

and you can check that it exists with [`Enum.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx):

```
if (! Enum.IsDefined(typeof(EModelType), yourInt)) throw new ArgumentException("Illegal type");
```

Comment: Great! That's what I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the value in the database is a string, then use:

```
EnumType x = (EnumType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumType), dr[0].ToString());
```

If the value in the database is a long, then use:

```
EnumType x = (EnumType)dr[0];
```

If you need the long value of an enum, use:

```
long x = (long)EnumType.SomeEnum
```

Comment: Thanks, your second solution was simply the one.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your enum with an `int` backing type, like this:

```
public enum EModelType : int
{
    StatStr = 1,
    HistStr = 6,
    HistVal = 7
}
```

Then, like Tim and Chris suggested, just cast or parse the integer from the database to your enum type.

Comment: That's what I meant by "use enumerators and overriding their values" yes